# NSURLSessionDownloadTask - read downloaded data before didFinishDownloading

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am trying to replace `NSURLConnection` with `NSURLSession`, but I found that with `NSURLSession` I couldn't read the intermediate data chunks like I did in `NSURLConnection` with the delegate method.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

I used to start using the data before completion. I am kind of streaming. How I can access the downloaded data before `NSURLSession` complete?

I notice there is a `(NSURL *)location` which is temporary saved data location from `NSURLSession` before completion, but I can I get this URL before completion?

Thanks

---

Tried this as suggested from Rob:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURLSessionTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
[task resume];
```

However, only didRecieveResponse was called

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition))completionHandler
```

but didReceiveData not called.

I tried to change the task to downloadTask

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate:self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask * downloadTask =[defaultSession downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
[downloadTask resume];
```

It works with the download delegate, but data delegate (didReceiveData) not called.

Anybody can tell me what did I get wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use the delegate-based rendition of `NSURLSession`, the `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` protocol includes a `didReceiveData` method, so you can instantiate a `NSURLSessionDataTask` and then write your own streaming code just like you would have with `NSURLConnection`:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self];
NSURLSessionTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
[task resume];
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to write your own streaming code, but want `NSURLSession` to stream this to a file for you and keep you informed of its progress, again, use the `delegate` based rendition of `NSURLSession`, create and `resume` a `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`:

```
NSURLSessionTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
[task resume];
```

Having done that, you can then implement the `didWriteData` method of the `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` protocol and it will inform you as data is written (obviously, as long as your app is in the foreground; if you use background session and the app is not active, your app is only re-activated when all the background tasks finish). But that way you get the best of both worlds, where `NSURLSession` does a streaming download, but will keep you informed of its progress.

But, if you're using `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`, you don't have access to the `NSURL` of the temporary file until the download is complete (and in `didFinishDownloadingToURL` you would move this temporary file to its permanent final location).

Comment: Thanks Rob for your quick reply. Sounds very good, I didn't know I could use dataTask to download file. Let me try and use the didReceiveData delegate method and get back to you. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Rob, I tried and tried but couldn't get it to work. Could you please take a look at my EDIT and see if there's anything wrong I've done. Thanks.

Comment: @user1256663 And did you call that `completionHandler` block that `didReceiveResponse` provided to you? I know the first time I used delegate-based `NSURLSession` I completely glossed over that critical parameter: It won't continue until you call that completion block. Anytime any of these delegate methods provide completion block (received response, received challenge, handling redirect), you _must_ call it.

Comment: That was it! Thanks Rob. I have been pulling my hair for so long.

Comment: Thanks Rob, again. I was just searching the same topic and everything you  wrote is correct. Unfortunatelly, dataTask can't be run in background (downloadTask can) ... so anyone reading this beware of this :)